# Objects returned by Get-SPOSite

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Where can I find detailed documentation for the properties of the objects returned by `Get-SPOSite` in PowerShell? According to the type information header created by `Export-Csv`, they are of type `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPOSite`. I'm looking specifically for information on the meaning of each of the properties.

Comment: I would start with [TenantManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/dn174983%28v%3doffice.15%29) and [TenantAdministration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/dn174891(v%3Doffice.15)) namespaces since a lot of properties are from their classes.

Comment: Thank you, and those were Interesting links with lots of SharePoint online classes. I don't know the MS object models well enough to recognize where these classes are used, but I still haven't found documentation on `SPOSite`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to use debug tool(I use PowerGUI Script Editor for PowerShell Script debug) to check the object usually.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your useful response. I was hoping for documentation of what each field means, but I'm starting to guess that it simply doesn't exist. In that situation, a debug tool would, like you suggested, help a person see what is actually in each object, allowing a user in many cases to reverse engineer the meaning of the field.